# python - set up time-step delay between two arrays

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

seq_u  and seq_y are three dimensions arrays:

```
seq_u  float32 (10L, 10L, 1L) 
seq_y  float32 (10L, 10L, 1L)
```

I want to set up a time-step delay between seq_u  and seq_y (i.e. seq_y(1) = seq_u(0), seq_y(2) = seq_u(1), ....)

[image: image1]

Here's my code:

```
seq_y[:, 1:, 0] = seq_u[:, :-1, 0]
```

It only add a zero as the first value. How to fix? In addition, how to set up 2 time-step delay? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how use the `np.pad` to shift arrays around:

```
import numpy as np

u = np.arange(1, 17).reshape(4, 4)
print u

[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16]]

y1 = np.pad(u, ((0, 0), (1, 0)), mode='constant')[:, :-1]
print y1

[[ 0  1  2  3]     # each row shifted one to the left
 [ 0  5  6  7]
 [ 0  9 10 11]
 [ 0 13 14 15]]

y2 = np.pad(u, ((0, 0), (3, 0)), mode='constant')[:, :-3]
print y2

[[ 0  0  0  1]    # each row shifted 3 to the right
 [ 0  0  0  5]
 [ 0  0  0  9]
 [ 0  0  0 13]]


y3 = np.pad(u, ((2, 0), (0, 0)), mode='constant', constant_values=(999,))[:-2, :]
print y3

[[999 999 999 999]   # each column shifted down 2
 [999 999 999 999]   # new spaces filled with 999
 [  1   2   3   4]
 [  5   6   7   8]]
```